# Vue. Prevent window close depending on vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

So I want to prevent my Vue App from closing the browser window if there is a certain value in the Vuex State. I think the problem I have is that Vuex store is not available in lifecycle hooks.

Here is what I'm trying:

```js
mounted: function () {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
            console.log('unload');
            if (this.$store.state.curOrder != ''){
                event.preventDefault()    
                event.returnValue = ""
            }
        }, false)
    },
```

When I try to close the browser window, the console log is correct, but then I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Any workaround so I can access Vuex before closing the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a scope issue, try like this.

Create a separate method.

```js
methods: {
    onClose(event) {
        console.log('unload');
        if (this.$store.state.curOrder != ''){
            event.preventDefault()    
            event.returnValue = ""
        }
    }
}
```

And for your listener change to:

`window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onClose);`

Comment: Nice! This way I can read the store. However, it doesnt prevent the window from closing. I'm using Chrome Versión 79

Comment: Preventing a window close is really bad practice. I wouldn't be surprised to find that Chrome does not allow that functionality.

Comment: Hmm true.. a pity this is an app for internal use, and users are always leaving documents blocked. Will try to figure an alternative, like saving the document before closing or something like that. Thanks